Lagrange's method applied to Earth-Sun system using NDSolve. Problems: Earth too fast and CM not (almost) centered
Good morning to all! I am trying to solve the two body problem for the Sun-Earth system. I make use of the Lagrangian Method and NDSolve; code is shown below:
Clear["Global`*"]
unMedio = 1/2;
vr1[t_] = D[r1[t], t];
vr2[t_] = D[r2[t], t];
omega1[t_] = D[theta1[t], t];
omega2[t_] = D[theta2[t], t];
lagrangiano[t_] := 
 unMedio m1 vr1[t]^2 + unMedio m1 (r1[t] omega1[t])^2 + 
  m1 k1/(r1[t] + r2[t]) + unMedio m2 vr2[t]^2 + 
  unMedio m2 (r2[t] omega2[t])^2 + m2 k2/(r1[t] + r2[t])

temp1 = D[lagrangiano[t], r1[t]]; temp2 = 
 D[lagrangiano[t], vr1[t]]; temp3 = D[temp2, t];
eq1 = temp1 == temp3
temp1 = D[lagrangiano[t], theta1[t]]; temp2 = 
 D[lagrangiano[t], omega1[t]]; temp3 = D[temp2, t];
eq2 = temp1 == temp3/(m1 r1[t]) // Simplify
temp1 = D[lagrangiano[t], r2[t]]; temp2 = 
 D[lagrangiano[t], vr2[t]]; temp3 = D[temp2, t];
eq3 = temp1 == temp3
temp1 = D[lagrangiano[t], theta2[t]]; temp2 = 
 D[lagrangiano[t], omega2[t]]; temp3 = D[temp2, t];
eq4 = temp1 == temp3/(m2 r2[t]) // Simplify
m1 = 5.9722*^24;
m2 = 1.9891*^30;
nc = 6.6743*^-11;
k1 = nc m2;
k2 = nc m1;
r20 = 50;
r10 = 147098074000 - r20;
w0 = Sqrt[k1/(r10 (r10 + r20)^2)]
sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, r1[0] ==  r10, r1'[0] == 0, 
    theta1[0] == 0, omega1[0] ==  w0, r2[0] == r20, r2'[0] == 0, 
    theta2[0] == \[Pi], omega2[0] == w0}, {r1[t], theta1[t], r2[t], 
    theta2[t]}, {t, 0, 365*86400}];
r1[t_] = r1[t] /. sol[[1, 1]];
theta1[t_] = theta1[t] /. sol[[1, 2]];
r2[t_] = r2[t] /. sol[[1, 3]];
theta2[t_] = theta2[t] /. sol[[1, 4]];
ParametricPlot[{r1[t] Cos[theta1[t]], r1[t] Sin[theta1[t]]}, {t, 0, 365*86400}, AspectRatio -> 1]

The actual graphic I get shows an orbit that, although circular (thanks to andreas' comment) is still not correct. As you can see, when I plot the graph for say 130 days, the orbit is almost closed.

It should take about 365 days to close, but it is actually showing earth moving much faster than it should. Further, the CM is not centered. I can't find the mistake(s). Any help will be much appreciated!
Cheers,
José

AspectRatio->Automatic...

Your Lagrangian is a strange animal: the potential of  the Kepler problem in cartesian coordinates is
$$V(r1,r2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r1^2+r2^2}}$$

Even though the code is written in Mathematica, this is not really question about Mathematica. This is a math problem, so it's off-topic here.

With AspectRatio->1 I get a circle

@Andreas Well, I don't think AspectRatio->1 is the right way to go here: Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1/2}], AspectRatio -> 1]

This is simply because your Lagrangian is wrong. It has two terms
m1 k1/(r1[t] + r2[t]) +  m2 k2/(r1[t] + r2[t])

so you are double counting the potential energy. Since the gravitational force is doubled, the earth has to move faster. You should replace the above terms by
m1 m2 nc/(r1[t] + r2[t])

which yields an expected answer.
ParametricPlot[{r1[t] Cos[theta1[t]], r1[t] Sin[theta1[t]]}, {t, 0, 
  365*86400}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]


